# Issue creating triangle mesh in PhysX

Tags: c++, 3d, physx

I've constructed a quick python script that reads a wavefront .obj file and outputs the verticies and faces to files. I have another C++ function that reads these files and creates a mesh based of-of those.

The issue that I'm experiencing is that this works perfectly sometimes, and other time not so much - with the same mesh. E.g. I start my PhysX program, and create 10 of the same objects of the same mesh and some of them look like this:

[image: Normal Mesh]

and others look like this:

[image: Broken Mesh]

The following C++ is the code that loads the verticies and triangles:

```
bool ModelLoader::LoadVertexFile(const std::string& fileLocation)
{
    std::ifstream file(fileLocation);
    if (!file) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to load vertex data\n";
        return false;
    }

    float x, y, z;
    vertexArray.clear();

    while (file >> x >> y >> z)
    {
        vertexArray.push_back(PhysicsEngine::PxVec3(x, y, z));
    }
    return true;
}

bool ModelLoader::LoadTrianglesFile(const std::string& fileLocation)
{
    std::ifstream file(fileLocation);
    if (!file) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to load vertex data\n";
        return false;
    }

    int x;
    triangleArray.clear();
    while (file >> x)
    {
        triangleArray.push_back(x);
    }
    return true;
}
```

This is the code for creating constructing the mesh

```
   CustomObject(const PxTransform& pose = PxTransform(PxIdentity), string vertfile = "", string trigfile = "") :
        StaticActor(pose)
    {

        modelLoader = new ModelLoader();
        if(!modelLoader->LoadVertexFile(vertfile))
            throw new Exception("Failed to load VertexFile.");
        if(!modelLoader->LoadTrianglesFile(trigfile))
            throw new Exception("Failed to load TrianglesFile.");

        PxTriangleMeshDesc mesh_desc;
        mesh_desc.points.count = (PxU32)modelLoader->vertexArray.size();
        mesh_desc.points.stride = sizeof(PxVec3);
        mesh_desc.points.data = &modelLoader->vertexArray.front();
        mesh_desc.triangles.count = (PxU32)modelLoader->triangleArray.size();
        mesh_desc.triangles.stride = 3 * sizeof(PxU32);
        mesh_desc.triangles.data = &modelLoader->triangleArray.front();

        CreateShape(PxTriangleMeshGeometry(CookMesh(mesh_desc)));
    }
```

So if anyone can help me figure out whats going wrong it would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think I had a similar issue and fixed by providing [contiguous 2D arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21943621/how-to-create-a-contiguous-2d-array-in-c)  either for vertices and for triangles (got a look to this [bunny mesh example](https://github.com/NVIDIA-Omniverse/PhysX/blob/release/104.2/physx/snippets/snippetfrustumquery/SnippetFrustumQuery.cpp#L305) in PhysX 5.1 and to the [docs](https://nvidia-omniverse.github.io/PhysX/physx/5.1.3/docs/Geometry.html#triangle-meshes))